# Why does Android studio insist in this deprecation warning?

Tags: android-studio, warnings, deprecation-warning, android-studio-electric-eel

Why do I get a deprecation warning in Android studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1, despite the fact that I am handling it? This happens no matter what the problem is.

This is my code where I get a deprecation warning for `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`:

```
public void fs(Window dialogWin) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        final WindowInsetsController insetsController = getWindow().getInsetsController();
        if (insetsController != null) insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
    } else
        dialogWin.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

And if I suppress the warning with a

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation");
```

I then get a Redundant suppression warning. The only workaround I found was to add

```
@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "RedundantSuppression"})
```

Silly.